# Querying a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

Community,

I got a data frame. The data frame consists of users, here 'ermu', 'joba' and 'mamu'. The values are correlation values based on ratings. Now I want to query the data frame by "show me the username with the highest correlation to my current user named 'joba'." How to achieve this with R?

Here is the data frame:

```
         ermu               joba               mamu
ermu     1.0                -0.83              -0.66
joba     -0.83              1.0                0.86
mamu     -0.66              0.86               1.0
```

Best regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the diagonal to NA (to exclude the correlations of 1) and query as follows:

```
diag(df)=NA
rownames(df)[which.max(df$joba)]
```

which returns

```
[1] "mamu"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Florian. That will bring me to a solution. Anyway, I got an error but I am pretty sure to figure that out: Error in correlationMatrix$joba : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Probably your dataframe is not a dataframe, it is a matrix. You can do `df = as.data.frame(df)` before running my code, then it should work.